# Unknown One-time pad key

Tags: cryptography, one-time-pad

I'm taking this new cryprography class and i'm kinda stuck. here is the problem:

> "You know that the word “good” (let’s say message m), consisting of 4 characters, has been encrypted, through the OTP, into a known ciphertext c1.
> You don’t know though the secret key k.
> The sender of the message re-uses the same key k to encrypt another message
> (let’ say m1) and computes a known ciphertext c2.
> Show that you can find out the unknown message m1."

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Search for "two time pad" (which is the name of this mistake). https://crypto.stackexchange.com/search?q=two+time+pad

Comment: Isn't clear `(m xor key  = c` ), since you know, `m` and `c1` you know ...

Comment: `m XOR key = c` and  `m1 XOR key = c1`.  If you XOR these two together you get `m XOR m1 = c XOR c1`.  You know m, c, and c1.  Solve for m1.